# Перезапуск скрипта после ответа сервера 502 ошибкой по средствам jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, php, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день! Делаю парсер, отдельный php является обработчиком, на вход принимает 2 параметра LIMIT_START и LIMIT для вытаскивания из БД предварительно созданного списка URL. Дальше по каждому URL проходится simple_html_dom и после успешной записи выводит LIMIT_START. Запуск скрипта осуществляется из другого файла с формой и jQurty скриптом. Скрипт по Ajax отправляет LIMIT_START и LIMIT  а полученный в ответ LIMIT_START наращивает на LIMIT обновляет поле в форме и с задержкой (setTimeout) в 1-1,5 секунды жмёт на кнопку отправить http://joxi.ru/mSOtU_3JTJA4A7YugLo .  Но каждые 20 - 30 итераций сервер возвращает 502 ошибку и скрипт приходится опять перезапускать вручную. Скажите возможно ли и как средствами jquery отследить 502 ответ сервера, чтобы запустить какую-нибудь функци которая отсчитает ещё 30 секунд и перезапустит парсер самостоятельно (тыкнется в кнопку "Start") ?

Comment: Никак не отвечу на сам поставленный вопрос, но настоятельно порекомендую не заниматься прямым запуском парсера из браузера. **Серверная работа должна выполняться на самом сервере из сервера с неограниченным временем выполнения и прочими плюшками.** Из браузера можно только вызывать триггер на выполнение этих заданий.

Answer (score 2):

Может

```
error: function(error) {
    alert('error; ');
}
```

Comment: @kff вроде как является - топикастер очень-очень пространно спросил, как в jQuery получить событие об ajax-ошибке